How can I find all recent todos with a specific tag?
I want to find all todos which has its CREATED property not more than ten days ago. Also, the todo has to be tagged "family".
I'm playing with this, but it's not really working sorting by the timestamp in CREATED.
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
  `("flt"
    "Todos created within the last 10 days tagged family"
    tags
    "+family+TODO=\"TODO\""
    ((org-agenda-entry-types '(:timestamp))
     (org-agenda-start-day "-10d")
     (org-agenda-span 10)
     (org-agenda-property-created t "CREATED")
     (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp ":CREATED:"))
     (org-agenda-time-grid nil)
     )))

